# spring session management not working

Tags: security, spring, session

In my spring application i add spring security. below i mentioned my security xml file.

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/businessCategory"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"   />
            <security:logout  logout-success-url="/businessCategory" />  
    </security:http>
```

That's works fine for me.
Then i add a session management for my application.after that my security is like below

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/businessCategory"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=1"   />
            <security:logout  logout-success-url="/businessCategory" />  
         **<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/ticketslk/sessionExpire"/>**
    </security:http>
```

Then i restart the server and run the app it goes to session expire page.
Then i typed the url again and run it works perfectly. Each and every time when server restarting, first time application goes to session expire page. I don't why that is happen. Does any body can help me.How can fixed that issue

I added security filter chain to  web.xml

```
  <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue here.

The browser stores the session id in a cookie and uses the same when it accesses the server.  Each time the server is restarted, the session id in the cookie is no longer valid.  Hence the session expired message.

To test it, after you restart the server and before you access the server, remove the session cookie from the browser.  You should not get the session expired page.

Comment: Its works fine. Thank you Raguram to sort out my issue.really i didn't know that before.Grate help